# writable zip ranges are not possible?

Tags: c++, c++14, range-v3

The following is failing:

```
#include <range/v3/view.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/zip.hpp>
#include <range/v3/utility/iterator.hpp>

// ...

std::vector< std::tuple<int, std::string> > const data{
   {1,"a"},
   {2,"b"},
   {3,"c"}
};
std::vector<int> vi(data.size());
std::vector<std::string> vs(data.size());

using namespace ranges;
copy(data,  view::zip(vi,vs) ); // error
```

clang says

```
No matching function for call to object of type 'const 
ranges::v3::with_braced_init_args<ranges::v3::copy_fn>'
```

Assuming this is by design, why?

And, how can I do this obvious thing with ranges?

Comment: that isn't relevant (someone referenced https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/867, then deleted the comment). back_inserter here is ranges::back_inserter. in fact, the issue is not even that. i updated the code in question to remove ambiguity. back_inserter'ed zip'ped ranges error the same way. using them would be more convenient of course.

Comment: I don't think it's specific with `zip`. All view must be InputRange.

Comment: i see.. maybe action then? but not seeing how it composes with zipped. well.. confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `copy` takes an output *iterator*, not an output *range*. So you need to call `begin` on the zip view and turn it into an iterator.
2. With that fixed, you run into a separate problem. `zip`ping two ranges produce a `pair` (well, a `common_pair`), but while tuples of two elements are assignable from pairs, pairs are not assignable from tuples of two elements. As a result, we can't do the equivalent of `*zip_iterator = *data.begin()`, and the concept check fails. If you make `data` a vector of `pair`s, then it would work.

Comment: (2) is arguably a bug. Tuple-like things should be assignable to each other.

Comment: ok, yes I was just going to point that out, and this Eric guy just jumped in :)

Comment: thanks it was dumb of me to use a range where output iter is expected. however in all fairness, the compiler error wasn't that useful. ironically, the concept-based synopsis of the story does not seem to have the satisfactory punch line the previous error novels had had :(  is sfinae the right tool for all this?

Comment: also it isn't clear how i can back insert into a zipped range.. hmm let me cook up another question for that

Comment: asking the back_inserter question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895996/write-to-a-zipped-back-inserted-ranges